# spring Kafka integration test listener not working (KAFKA JsonDeserializer)

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

> **KafkaConsumerConfig.java**

```
@Bean
public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();

    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, pool);



    props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, StringDeserializer.class);

    return props;
}

public ConsumerFactory<String, MetadataFileIntegrationDTO> consumerFactoryMetadataFileIntegration() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new StringDeserializer(),
            new JsonDeserializer<>(MetadataFileIntegrationDTO.class, false));
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MetadataFileIntegrationDTO> kafkaListenerContainerFactoryMetadataFileIntegration() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MetadataFileIntegrationDTO> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setErrorHandler(new KafkaErrorHandler());
    factory.setMessageConverter(new StringJsonMessageConverter());
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactoryMetadataFileIntegration());

    return factory;
}
```

> **MetadataFileCustom.Java**

```
@KafkaListener(topics = TOPIC,
        groupId = GROUP,
        containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactoryMetadataFileIntegration")
public void streamListener(MetadataFileIntegrationDTO metadataFileIntegrationDTO) {
    log.info(TOPIC+ "===> RECEIVED MESSAGE:" + metadataFileIntegrationDTO);
    metadataFileService.save(metadataFileIntegrationDTO);
}
```

> if I change my **consumerFactoryMetadataFileIntegration** to

```
public ConsumerFactory consumerFactoryMetadataFileIntegration() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(consumerConfigs(), new StringDeserializer(),
            new StringDeserializer());
}
```

works, but the sonar complains..
[image]

**Error:
Listener failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only String, Bytes, or byte[] supported**

Comment: You already have a factory bean defined with json deserializer. Why do you want to use strings?

Answer (score 1):

You can imagine the consumer flow with MessageConverter like:

1. Native deserializer (`StringDeserializer` in your case) deserializes `byte[]` messages to `String` messages.
2. Consumer.poll() returns these `String` messages.
3. Your MessageConverter (`StringJsonMessageConverter`) converts these `String` messages to your type `MetadataFileIntegrationDTO` (determined by params in @KafkaListener)

---

So when you defined your native deserializer as `JsonDeserializer` (corresponding to `ConsumerFactory<String, MetadataFileIntegrationDTO>`), the consumer.poll() returned `MetadataFileIntegrationDTO` messages, and that wasn't the type the `StringJsonMessageConverter` can process (you could see **Only String, Bytes, or byte[] supported**)

And when you changed `JsonDeserializer` to `StringDeserializer`, the corresponding `ConsumerFactory` was `ConsumerFactory<String, String>`. This means that when you create a new `Consumer` from this `ConsumerFactory`, the consumer.poll() returns `String`.